# Simple authentication / login

Tags: asp.net, authentication, session-state

I'm trying to avoid using forms auth for a very light application. The site consists of only one page (with ajax), and a login page.

I'm thinking of handling authentication as such:

1. User logs in, "userid" session variable is set
2. Page refresh and ajax calls check for the "userid" session variable
3. If session times out, "userid" will return as null and user is logged out
4. Upon manual logout, "userid" is set to null

Any glaring reasons why this wouldn't work?

Comment: It very much depends on the content of the site. If they have to enter personal information (e.g. address, zipcode etc) it's good with a more secure login form.

Answer (score 1):

For authentication, implement your own MembershipProvider with your authentication logic (more details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)).

You application will be more secure and you can take advantages from using login controls.

Comment: what is more secure about this method? Aren't both equally subject to cookie tampering / impersonation?